# How to hide all children div except a specific one with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="target">
    <div id="exclude"></div>
    <div></div>
    ...
</div>
```

`$('#target').children().hide();` will hide all.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

What you're wanting to do is hide all of the *siblings* of a particular element. That's relatively simple with jQuery using the [`.siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method:

```
​$("#exclude").siblings().hide();​​​​
```

This will hide all elements on the same level, in the same parent element.

Answer (score 10):

I believe that  `$('#target > div').not('#exclude').hide()` should do what you want.

Or alternately if you want sub-children that are divs too, `$('#target div').not('#exclude').hide()`

Comment: Tnx bro, Fast Easy and Clean!

Answer (score 2):

Use the **[:not](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/not)** selector

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#target').children().hide();
$('#exclude').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the "not" selector with the id that you want to exclude?

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/not#selector

Also, the obvious answer would be to follow it with a $('#exclude').show()